# Closure of the image of the unit ball in $C[0,1]$ under a given linear operator

Tags: real-analysis

If $C=C[0,1]$ and $T:C\rightarrow C$ is the linear operator $f\mapsto \int_0^x f(t)dt$ and $B$ is the unit ball in $C$, what is the closure of $TB$?

I'm practicing for a prelim and I need to know this in order to make progress on one of the practice problems. Thanks!

Comment: Under what metric is the unit ball defined? Sup norm? Absolute integral? Square integral?

Comment: It doesn't specify, so I'm assuming it is the sup norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f\in B,$ then $Tf(0)=0,$  and $Tf$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $\le 1.$